# removeEventListener("timeUpdate", myFunction) is unstable during video play

Tags: javascript, event-handling, html5-video, removeeventlistener

An event listener is added once my video starts playing. That is

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("timeUpdate", myFunction);
```

and then just before the video ends I want something to happen (perhaps a fade out) along with the last few seconds of the video (or to keep things simple I'm just going to write something like `alert("goodbye");`) instead.

and when I use this piece of code

```
 var myVideo = document.getElementById ("myVideo");
 function myFunction(){
   if(myVideo.currentTime >= (myVideo.duration-3) )
   {
     alert("this goodbye message is supposed to be displayed only once and exactly three seconds before the video ends");
     myVideo.removeEventListener("timeupdate", myFunction);
   }
  }
```

it works in Chrome but it's unstable. Sometimes it works fine but other times the alert keeps popping a few times before the event listener is actually removed (which is bad in my case). In Firefox it is even worse as it fires many times.
I know that different browsers make `timeupdate` event fire at very different intervals.

So what do you think? Should I give up on the
`addEventListener()`
`removeEventListener()`
couple and use
`setInterval()``clearInterval()` to check where the playhead is and do stuff when the time comes.
That way instead of browser dependent time intervals I could set my own time interval for consistency. But does anybody know if there is a reliable way to do this with `timeUpdate`?

Answer (score 0):

I used a timer instead and now it works perfectly.

```
var checkThePlayheadPositionTenTimesASecond = setInterval(myTimer, 100);
function myTimer()
      {
        if(myVideo.currentTime >= (myVideo.duration-3) )
           {
             alert("this video is going to end in three seconds");
             clearInterval(checkThePlayheadPositionTenTimesASecond);
           }
      }
```

Still I'm going to leave this post active in case anyone has to say anything.